# Preferred image dimensions for UITableViewCell with default style

Tags: ios, uitableview, retina-display

**What are the preferred image dimensions for UITableViewCell thumbnail images**?  I'm leaning towards 48x48 for original iPhone/iPad and 96x96 for iPhone 4's Retina display.  I've tested on iPhone 3G, iPhone 4 and original iPad and they look good.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use 48 x 48 for `UITableViewCell` image. Good choice!